# Anyway to fix wire sensitive touch screen?

Tags: touchscreen

The touch screen of this smart-phone is capacitive type and it is very annoying when touch by ear-phone cable or any other cable make it trigger actions. I am afraid of it. In earlier phones that I had owned did not had this unwanted extra feature. This phone is developed by ZTE in China with Indian local branding.

Comment: Try decreasing pointer speed as mentioned [here](https://www.inclusiveandroid.com/content/how-control-sensitivity-your-screen)